# File upload issue in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have two file upload api's. One for uploading resume and other for uploading profile picture.
Upload resume api takes one file as parameter. I tried below code.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPTjnjok43Hg6SN0w
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

${__FileToString(${P_ResumeFileLocation},,)}

------WebKitFormBoundaryPTjnjok43Hg6SN0w--
```

API is passing. However if I download the uploaded file, it is not showing any data.
Later i tried multipart/form-data option and gave file location in file upload tab.
API is getting passed and I can see data correctly after downloading same.

I went ahead and tried the same for upload picture api too. This api needs file, width and height parameters to be passed.
I created two parameters in parameters tab and placed the file details in file-upload tab. API failed saying invalid method. Actually API takes file as first parameter and width, height later. In jmeter request tab I can see file is passed at last.

And i tried below code also:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRo2HSZXcGbDUiLyU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="samplepicture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

${__FileToString(${P_ProfileImageLocation},,)}
------WebKitFormBoundaryRo2HSZXcGbDUiLyU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="width"

1000
------WebKitFormBoundaryRo2HSZXcGbDUiLyU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="height"

1000
------WebKitFormBoundaryRo2HSZXcGbDUiLyU--
```

API is passing but i don't see a proper image when I download it.

I recorded the flow using fiddler. And I can re-issue the api request in fiddler successfully and can view image properly after downloading. I tried copying raw data from fiddler request, but no luck

I need to performance test those two api's using jmeter. Kindly let me know where I'm making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you can "record the flow using fiddler" you should be able to "record the flow" using JMeter, it's smart enough to generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) by capturing the request from the browser.

Just make sure to **copy the picture to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation** during recording otherwise it will fail, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) for more details.

P.S. "Raw" traffic from Fiddler can be replayed using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler

Comment: I have request recorded using blazemeter. It is failing.